# is there a way to duplicate a row?

Tags: sql, powerset

I want for something that works the opposite way that a COUNT, that's like a inverse `GROUP BY` (a `SPLIT BY`?) but that you can work with more freely.

So far I've seen all "commands" are for restrictions or specification, meaning that you can't create a bigger table/set that the one you already have. I am talking about creating some sort of dynamic construction of sets.

Any way to, for instance, create a power set or an "exponential" cross join' (each row joined with size_in_rows copies of himself)? Or some sort of recursion?

An example of what I would need:

I have a table with a couple of fields, each one contains info and a "count" integer value. I need to SELECT __ and send that many "count" copies of the same exact row, to read it one by one with another program outside of the database.

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Provide a concrete example, with data in a *text* table in the question.

Comment: You could use a function like `generate_series()` to generate many rows based on a counter. What's the specific database?

Comment: It would be better if you provide a set of example.

Comment: Depending on DB you could use a recursive CTE for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach for SQL Server: [Fiddle Example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=478db05c77f6b3e56292c3ea8a448265)

```
declare @rowToBeCopiedId bigint = 1
, @count int = 10

; with noRowsToInsertCte
(
    select 1 x
    where @count > 0
    union all
    select x + 1
    from noRowsToInsertCte 
    where @count > x
)
insert MyTable (col1, col2)
select col1, col2
from MyTable
cross join noRowsToInsertCte
where id = @rowToBeCopiedId
```

If instead of duplicating records in the database you just want to duplicate the record in the result set, you can do it as below.  This example uses a column in the data to say how many times the related record should be repeated, and uses a view to allow you to easily reuse this logic:

```
create view vMyTableWithCount as
with innerCte as 
(
    select id
    , col1
    , col2
    , cnt
    , 1 i
    from MyTable
    where cnt > 0

    union all

    select id
    , col1
    , col2
    , cnt
    , i + 1
    from innerCte
    where i < cnt
) 
select *
from innerCte
```

For more context, please see the [fiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=478db05c77f6b3e56292c3ea8a448265).

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify your DBMS, but with [PostgreSQL](http://postgresql.org/) this is really easy:

```
select t.*
from the_table t
  cross join generate_series(1, t.count)
order by t.id
```

Assuming the primary key column of the table is named `id`, then `order by t.id` keeps the "duplicated" rows together.

Comment: FYI: For SQL Server you can use a similar approach; see this post for how to implement `generate_series` there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28400185/361842

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
SELECT * FROM T
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM T WHERE count>1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM T WHERE count>2
```

should get you there but quickly becomes impractical if you want insane counts to work as well.

Some more things : you are not constructing sets, you are constructing bags.  Sets can't have duplicates, by definition.

Cross join does not suit your purpose because what it does is produce more columns, where you are after producing more rows.